# Customize Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I want to customize the appearance of my form like removing all the buttons (maximize, minimize, exit). I also want to customize my titlebar. Is there any way to do this ?

I'm aware of the FormBorderStyle, but what I want is to atleast add a custom titlebar at the top of this form with my own color and style and like a border around the form. Can it be possible ?

Comment: What language? C#, VB, C/C++? Also, what evironment? Windows, Linux w/ Gnome, KDE, etc.?

Comment: I'm using c# Windows form Application in my Windows 7

Comment: Have you done some searches online? There's a lot of material. [Google.com](http://www.google.com/) is your friend. Show us what you've tried and hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the minimize and maximize buttons, in the form properties and turn it to false, or simply by code:

```
this.MaximizeBox = false;
this.MinimizeBox = false;
```

you can also hide the buttons by codes

```
button1.Hide();
```

or simply disable it

```
button1.Enabled = false;
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah , pretty much I'm done with this. What about the titlebar ? How do I customize it ?

Comment: The title bar is in the properties of the form and find the text, its form1 in default and you can change it to you desired title

Comment: you can also change your border style there, in the formborder style :)

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do it.

1. Hook Windows APIs to redraw the form border(kind of difficult.)
2. Use "none" then draw a title bar (GDI+) just looks like you have it!

Comment: Sorry ! are we in c# Windows Form Application ?

Comment: yes we are. C# has very useful namespace for GDI+ which is System.Drawing

Comment: Oh, yeah I saw it there but maybe this is pretty tough for me. I'm just a beginner in c#. I'm not actually aware of this GDI+.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but these are only two ways to deal with your purpose. What you want to do is advanced skill in every programming langusge.

Comment: Its "beginner-intermediate". There are much more advanced topics than GDI+.. :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to say it's a long way to go from your step now. You can read book about C# GDI+ Programming.